# PHP - how can i get list of all headers

Tags: php, javascript

I use a php proxy to bypass JS cross domain issue.
I want to pass some of the headers from the client to the destination server.

How can i receive a list of all headers?

Comment: Either PHP has nothing to do with this, or JavaScript has nothing to do with this.

Comment: PHP has a lot to do with that, and most probably that JS programmers had to deal with that problem before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built in function called [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) which you should be able to make use of.

Comment: Ah, `get_headers` gets a list of headers that will be sent by the server TO the client. The question asks about passing headers sent from the client.

Comment: Then you'll use `apache_request_headers()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request headers by calling [`getallheaders`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php).

Answer (score 0):

Would not do that via PHP.
See if this is suitable for you, if you use apache2: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

getallheaders() and apache_request_headers() don't seem to work on my server.. I'm assuming it's because its only available "under FastCGI" or "when PHP was installed as an Apache module." (according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

However, a comment by jrabbit on the same page details a replacement function which seems to work for me:

```
<?php 
if (!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) { 
    eval(' 
        function apache_request_headers() { 
            foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) { 
                if (substr($key,0,5)=="HTTP_") { 
                    $key=str_replace(" ","-",ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",substr($key,5))))); 
                    $out[$key]=$value; 
                } 
            } 
            return $out; 
        } 
    '); 
} 
?>
```

User limalopex.eisfux.de has another implementation on the same page which I have not tested.

Comment: What server are you using (Apache, Nginx, IIS?) and how are you handling PHP (FPM / FastCGI, mod_php?)